# Update Elasticsearch Index from HTML/JQuery button submit

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, elasticsearch

I have a basic Elasticsearch index with the below **Type** and **Properties**.

**Index** – escalations

**Type** – escalation

**Properties (text)** – name, user_id, status(optionID), team, timestamp

http://my_endpoint.com:9200/escalations/

```
{"escalations":{"mappings":{"escalation":{"properties":{"incident":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"pd_user_id":{"type":"string"},"response":{"type":"string"},"team":{"type":"string"},"timestamp":{"type":"string"}}}}}}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Call Logger</h3>
<br>
    <h2><div class="Name"></h2>
    <h2><div class="Team"></h2>
    <h2><div class="Email"></div></h2>
    <br>
<select name="option" id="status_id">
  <option value="1">[No number listed]</option>
  <option value="2">[Not answered]</option>
  <option value="3">[Answered – not oncall – assisted with issue]</option>
  <option value="4">[Answered – not oncall – unavailable]</option>
  <option value="5">[Answered – oncall - unavailable]</option>
  <option value="6">[Answered – oncall - available]</option>
    </select>
     <fieldset>
     <button name="Log" type="submit" id="Log-submit">Log</button>
     </fieldset>

  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS** Script to update Index

Can I use something like to below to update my index with information from the HTML page.

Example,

Values from

```
<h2><div class="Name"></h2>
<h2><div class="Team"></h2>
id="status_id"
```

On click of **#log-submit** To then make a API PUT call to insert these values in my index? Please excuse me if I have not explained this the best I can, I am very new to elasticsearch.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Log-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(e.target);
        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
    $.ajax({
      data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
        "text": text // Update index with Name, Team, Timestamp 
      }),
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      type: 'PUT',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: 'http://my_endpoint.com:9200/escalations/'
    });
  });
});
```

I know I will probably have to add a `var text = .....` here, but I am not sure....I know I'm not far off getting what I need. Any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Comment: To update a document in Elasticsearch, you first need to know its "_id". Once you know the id, you can update the document directly by partially updating it or by overwriting the entire document.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I dont know the ID as a new record is to be created each time. I thought if I left it blank ES would create a id for me.

Comment: Yes. Definitely. ES will create it for you, for that you have to do a POST request. But for updating a document you will need ID or else you have to do a work around. Kindly let me know your exact requirement so I can help better.